# Проблема в input range, съезжает подсказка значения

Tags: html, css

Проблема в `.range > output` в свойстве `left`

Он двигает `output` в процентах от левого края.

Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему?

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 60px auto 20px;
}
.range {
    width: 100%;
    --completed: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / (var(--max) - var(--min)) * 100);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 22px 0 0 0;
}
.range__progress {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #BD3E8A 0%, #3F7446 90.48%);
}
.range__progress::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: -1px;
    width: calc((100% - var(--completed) * 1%) + (var(--completed) / 100) * 16px);
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.range > input {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: grab;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
}
.range > input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background: #84566B;
}
.range > input::-moz-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background: #84566B;
}
.range > input::-ms-thumb {
    appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background: #84566B;
}
.range > output {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    top: -30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    left: calc(((var(--value) - var(--min)) / (var(--max) - var(--min))) * 100%);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.range > output::after {
    content: var(--text-value);
}
.range > output::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 8px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="range" style='--min:1; --max:200; --value:38; --text-value:"38";'>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="38" oninput="this.parentNode.style.setProperty('--value',this.value); this.parentNode.style.setProperty('--text-value', JSON.stringify(this.value))">
    <output></output>
    <div class='range__progress'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде получилось решить проблему

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 60px auto 20px;
}
.range {
    width: 100%;
    --completed: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / (var(--max) - var(--min)) * 100);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 22px 0 0 0;
}
.range__progress {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #BD3E8A 0%, #3F7446 90.48%);
}
.range__progress::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: -1px;
    width: calc((100% - var(--completed) * 1%) + (var(--completed) / 100) * 16px);
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.range > input {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: grab;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
}
.range > input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background: #84566B;
}
.range > input::-moz-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background: #84566B;
}
.range > input::-ms-thumb {
    appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background: #84566B;
}
.range__output {
    width: calc(100% - 24px);
    position: relative;
}
.range__output > output {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    top: -58px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    left: calc(((var(--value) - var(--min)) / (var(--max) - var(--min))) * 100%);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.range__output > output::after {
    content: var(--text-value);
}
.range__output > output::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 8px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="range" style='--min:1; --max:200; --value:38; --text-value:"38";'>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="38" oninput="this.parentNode.style.setProperty('--value',this.value); this.parentNode.style.setProperty('--text-value', JSON.stringify(this.value))">
    <div class='range__output'><output></output></div>
    <div class='range__progress'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```